# Ubuntu crashed and Thunderbird lost all accounts (second time)

Tags: 20.04, thunderbird

This happened at least the second time this month. I'm not sure if it has anything to do with crashing but I noticed that it's the second time all accounts disappeared from Thunderbird like it was freshly installed.

[image]

Do you know where is the problem?

**EDIT**

```
milano@milano-desktop:~$ ls -la /home/milano/snap/thunderbird/common/.thunderbird/
total 40
drwx------  8 milano milano 4096 čen 30 11:18  .
drwxr-xr-x  5 milano milano 4096 dub 11  2020  ..
drwx------ 12 milano milano 4096 čen 25 21:10  50eiw0ah.default-beta
drwx------  4 milano milano 4096 čen 30 11:18 'Crash Reports'
-rw-rw-r--  1 milano milano  181 čen 30 11:18  installs.ini
drwx------ 13 milano milano 4096 pro 26  2020  ohzvuyl2.default
drwx------  2 milano milano 4096 dub 11  2020 'Pending Pings'
-rw-r--r--  1 milano milano  534 čen 30 11:18  profiles.ini
drwx------  9 milano milano 4096 čen 30 17:56  t5oh24il.default-beta-2
dr

wx------ 12 milano milano 4096 čen 30 13:12  tfk8s9n1.default-beta-1
```

**EDIT2**

```
milano@milano-desktop:~/snap/thunderbird/common/.thunderbird$ cat profiles.ini 
[Profile3]
Name=default-beta-2
IsRelative=1
Path=t5oh24il.default-beta-2

[Profile2]
Name=default-beta-1
IsRelative=1
Path=tfk8s9n1.default-beta-1

[Profile1]
Name=default-beta
IsRelative=1
Path=50eiw0ah.default-beta

[Install4455C541FCCFC69D]
Default=50eiw0ah.default-beta
Locked=1

[Profile0]
Name=default
IsRelative=1
Path=ohzvuyl2.default
Default=1

[Install3F74DF0047DC6711]
Default=tfk8s9n1.default-beta-1
Locked=1

[General]
StartWithLastProfile=1
Version=2

[Install578759B957B8C6D4]
Default=t5oh24il.default-beta-2
Locked=1
```

Comment: Look in `/home/[your-user]/.thunderbird`. Is there more than one directory starting with random letters? Or just one?

Comment: @Jos There is no such directory there.

Comment: Hi @Milano: Please look on "/home/snap/thunderbird/common/.thunderbird" randomletters.default

Comment: @jpbrain  I've added the content of the directory to the bottom of the question.

Comment: ok: You have 3  candidates. Can you cat profiles.ini? and also do du -sh "\*.defa\*"

Comment: @jpbrain Added to the bottom.

Comment: The one that says "Default=1" is the active one. Depending on the size of each ".default" you should figure out which one has your data.

Comment: So was it really _Ubuntu_ that crashed, i.e. the Linux kernel? Or wasn't it rather _Thunderbird_? Otherwise Thunderbird wouldn't have recorded a crash. If the kernel crashes, there is no way an application can still write a crash file.

Comment: @jpbrain It works, thanks!

Comment: @HuHa Ubuntu crash might have been a symptom of Thunderbird crash... anyways I needed to restart PC.

Comment: Should I post an answer or you close it?

Comment: @jpbrain Feel free to post the answer.